# Is there a difference between (local), '.' and localhost?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I've used all three of these when making local programmatic connections to databases. Is there any real difference between them?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The final result is the same. The difference is:

- 'localhost' resolves at the TCP/IP level and is equivalent to the IP address 127.0.0.1
- Depending on the application "(local)" could be just an alias for 'localhost'. In SQLServer, '(local)' and '.' mean that the connection will be made using the named pipes (shared memory) protocol within the same machine (doesn't need to go through the TCP/IP stack).

That's the theory. In practice, I don't think there is substantial difference in performance or features if you use either one of them.

Comment: In practice, there is one slight difference in that you should check which protocol is enabled. Sometimes only certain protocols are enabled by default, which can be seen and changed easiest in SQL Server Configuration Manager. That would make a big difference if you're connecting via TCP/IP but only named pipes is enabled, for example.

Comment: I recently noticed that when in the context of the current server, you can refer to the current instance without specifying the name. I created a job and the server name would not accept an instance name along with localhost (ex. localhost\SQLEXPRESS) but it knows (local) without specifying the instance name. The same is true for the data source of SSIS where it knows that the current instance as (local) without specifying the actual instance name.

Answer (score 1):

They are generally synonyms.  However, it depends on the application you are configuring.  As long as the app understands what you mean, it shouldn't result in a performance loss.  At least, not one you have to root out prematurely, if you get my drift.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the dot ***"."*** and ***"local"*** are windows application terms, not a "standard" term, ***localhost*** resolves to ***127.0.0.1*** in the TCP/IP level so if you want to make sure you are "compatible" across platforms you should use either localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: "localhost" is not a magic or reserved word; its definition exists in /etc/hosts, or \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS, or…

Comment: @tzot When did I say that localhost is a magic or reserved word? On the contrary, I said that the dot and local are more SQL-Server / windows naming standards and that localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 by the hosts file, usually both on unix and windows. Care to read?