# SQL connection issue via local and localhost

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Code environment:

- .Net Framework 4.6.1
- Web API
- Entity Framework
- SQL Server 2017 Developer

The situation is :
When I use (localhost) in connection string in web config.
(something like this)

```
connectionString="data source=(localhost);initial catalog=CN_CHANNELTREE;user id=LOA_WEB;password=BugsFor#;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

It gives me an error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

But when I change (localhost) to (local), it connected well.
And when I connect to SQL Server via SSMS, the local will give me a network-related error and the localhost will connected well.

And meanwhile, my buddy was running the code with (localhost) in connection string properly.

So I'm totally confused. Is anyone can explan this?

Comment: `localhost` is a loopback address, and will link to `127.0.0.1`. This essentially means your machine only. There is a change that your hostname is local, maybe due to an edited `hosts` file?

Comment: See this question, maybe can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155733/is-there-a-difference-between-local-and-localhost

Comment: Are you sure your buddy was using `(localhost)` (with parentheses) and not just `localhost`?

Comment: In your connection string, use `localhost` rather than `(localhost)`. Or use `(local)`. Or use `.` (just a DOT)

Comment: @JoeWhite, Yea, the thing is, I copied the code from him, and I have to change (localhost) to (local) to make the code run properly

Comment: just use `./SQLEXPRESS`